# I am sending data through postman using json as body type to add the task but still the data is null. What is wrong in this code?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, backend

This is the code of my `RestController`

```java
package com.training.Taskdemo.rest;

import com.training.Taskdemo.entity.Task;
import com.training.Taskdemo.service.TaskService;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TaskRestController {

    private TaskService thetask;
    public TaskRestController(TaskService taskDetail) {
        thetask = taskDetail;
    }

    @GetMapping("/tasks")
    public List<Task> findAll() {
        return thetask.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/addTask")
    public Task addTask(@RequestBody Task task) {
        task.setId(0);
        Task taskDetail = thetask.add(task);
        return taskDetail;
    }

    @GetMapping("/tasks/{taskId}")
    public Task getTask(@PathVariable int taskId) {
        Task fetchTask = thetask.findById(taskId);

        if(fetchTask == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Task id not found");
        }
        return fetchTask;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/tasks/{taskId}")
    public String deleteTask(@PathVariable int taskId) {
        Task taskDetail = thetask.findById(taskId);
        if(taskDetail == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Task id not found");
        }
    thetask.delete(taskId);
    return "Deleted task id "+ taskId;
    }

}
```

This is the code of my `TaskDAO`

```java
package com.training.Taskdemo.dao;

import com.training.Taskdemo.entity.Task;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.TypedQuery;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class TaskDAOImpl implements TaskDAO {

    private EntityManager theEntityManager;

    @Autowired
    public TaskDAOImpl(EntityManager entityManager){
        theEntityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Task> findAll() {
        TypedQuery<Task> theQuery = theEntityManager.createQuery("From Task",Task.class);

        List<Task>taskDetail = theQuery.getResultList();
        return taskDetail;
    }

    @Override
    public Task findById(int theId) {
        Task taskDetail = theEntityManager.find(Task.class, theId);
        return taskDetail;
    }

    @Override
    public Task add(Task theTask) {
        System.out.println(theTask);
        Task addTask = theEntityManager.merge(theTask);
        return addTask;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(int theId) {
        Task taskdelete = theEntityManager.find(Task.class, theId);
        theEntityManager.remove(taskdelete);
    }
}
```

This is the code of `TaskService`

```java
package com.training.Taskdemo.service;

import com.training.Taskdemo.dao.TaskDAO;
import com.training.Taskdemo.entity.Task;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class TaskServiceImpl implements TaskService {

    private TaskDAO taskRepository;
   
    @Autowired
    public TaskServiceImpl(TaskDAO thetask){
        taskRepository = thetask;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Task> findAll() {
        return taskRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Task findById(int theId) {
        return taskRepository.findById(theId);
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public Task add(Task task) {
        return taskRepository.add(task);
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void delete(int theId) {
        taskRepository.delete(theId);
    }
}
```

This is my `Task` class

```
package com.training.Taskdemo.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="task")
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="task_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="Task_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="task_priority")
    private String priority;

    public Task(){

    }

    public Task(String name, String priority) {
        this.name = name;
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public void setPriority(String priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Task{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", priority='" + priority + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

[I am sending data and it give me null data]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUWpi.png

I am using mysql database and all the other method like get, delete work fine but when I try to send the data of adding task by postman then the data inserted in the database are null not the value just as I passed.

Comment: Please, can you provide the entity Task class?

Comment: From the screenshot provided I would say your request body is wrong. You should use the JSON attributes and not the database column names. Something like this: `{"name":"learn Java","priority":"high"}`